# Fix the whole page except one main content div

Tags: jquery, css, position

May I know how to fix the position of whole page and make it unmovable when user scroll except a div that shows the main content? Any css or jquery for this trick? Thanks.

Comment: like this: http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=202/202.css ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add `position: fixed;` to all div elements that you want to be scrolled with the page.

like:

```
    #example {     
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    }
```

So in brief: add this to everything except the main content div.